# how to close a java frame with threads

Tags: java, multithreading, awt, frame

I have a java frame that I want to close it automatically after 3 or 4 seconds. I found out I must used threads. but I dont know how exactly to do it, this a dumy part of my code :

```
package intro;

import java.awt.*;
import java.io.IOException;
//import view.LangMenu;

public class IntroClass extends Frame {

    private int _screenWidth = 0;
    private int _screenHeight = 0;
    private int _screenCenterx = 0;
    private int _screenCentery = 0;

    //private static final String SOUND_PATH="/sounds/introSound.midi";
    public IntroClass() {
        Toolkit thisScreen = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit();
        Dimension thisScrrensize = thisScreen.getScreenSize();

        _screenWidth = thisScrrensize.width;
        _screenHeight = thisScrrensize.height;
        _screenCenterx = _screenWidth / 2;
        _screenCentery = _screenHeight / 2;
        setBackground(Color.pink);
        Label lbl = new Label("Welcome To Dots Game. Samaneh Khaleghi", Label.CENTER);
        add(lbl);
        setUndecorated(true);
        setLocation((_screenCenterx*50)/100,_screenCentery-(_screenCentery*50)/100);
        setSize((_screenWidth * 50) / 100, (_screenHeight * 50) / 100);

        WaitClass r = new WaitClass();
        r.start();
        view.DotsBoardFrame d=new view.DotsBoardFrame();
                main.Main.showScreen(d);
    }

    class WaitClass extends Thread {

        boolean running = true;

        public void run() {
            while (running) {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(50);
                } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }                
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

in your frame start a new thread and pass to it your frame instance, and after a specific period of time close it.

```
class MyThread extends Thread {

  private JFrame frame;
  //-- getters and setters for frame

  public void run() {
    Thread.sleep(1000); //close the frame after 1 second.
    frame.close();
  }

}
```

and in your JFrame class, in the constructor specifically put the following line of code:

```
MyThread th = new MyThread();
th.setFrame(this);
th.start();
```

Comment: Thanks Omar, I am gonna try it :)

Comment: Bad idea to manipulate an AWT component from any thread except the EDT.

Comment: @user261002: If its working means give the credit to the man Omar. You asked 9 questions,but you didn't accept any ans.

Answer (score 6):

Although AWT is supposed to be thread-safe, it isn't really. So I suggest, like Swing, do all the GUI manipulation on the AWT Event Dispatch Thread (EDT).

For this particular task, `javax.swing.Timer` should do the trick. (Although it is in the `javax.swing` package, there is nothing Swing-specific about it.)

Also I would strongly suggest not extending classes unless you really have to. There is very little reason ever to extend `Thread` or `Frame` (unfortunately there are lots of bad examples and old tutorials out there).

Answer (score 2):

You can use a [Timer](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html) and let it take care of threads for you.